# Rename Element and retain attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to rename the mattext node to text, but retain its attributes and all the child node/attributes

**Input XML**

```
<material>
  <mattext fontface="Tahoma">
    <p style="white-space: pre-wrap">
      <font size="11">Why are the astronauts in the video wearing special suits? (Select two)</font>
    </p>
  </mattext>
</material>
```

Output

```
<material>
  <text fontface="Tahoma">
    <p style="white-space: pre-wrap">
      <font size="11">Why are the astronauts in the video wearing special suits? (Select two)</font>
    </p>
  </text>
</material>
```

I have used the following xsl:

```
<xsl:template name="content">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Build stem -->
<xsl:template match="mattext">
    <text>
        <!-- Option text -->
        <xsl:call-template name="content"/>
    </text>
</xsl:template>
```

But it does not retain the initial fontface attribute and seems to output plain text stripping the tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can understand your result if that is your complete XSLT. You are inly matching one element, the <mattext>. All others are handled by the default behavior which is to copy the text nodes. I guess you want an [Identity Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with a special handling of the <mattext> element:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mattext">
    <text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </text>
</xsl:template>
```