# XML to XML via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylexslt3.xslt"?>
<team>
    <teaminfo>
        <logo source="logomym.jpg"/>
        <teampage address="http://www.site.com/"/>
        <name> Team name </name>
        <team_photo source="teamphoto.jpg"/>
        <game> Game1 </game>
        <achievements>
            <premiere_tournaments>
                <tournament>
                    <logoevent source="event1.jpg"/>
                    <tournament_name> tournament name </tournament_name>
                    <placing> 1 </placing>
                    <prize_pool>
                        <earned_prize> 10600 </earned_prize>
                        <average_prize> 4454 </average_prize>
                    </prize_pool>
                </tournament>
                <tournament>
                    <logoevent source="event2.jpg"/>
                    <tournament_name> tournament name </tournament_name>
                    <placing> 3 </placing>
                    <prize_pool>
                        <earned_prize> 10600 </earned_prize>
                        <average_prize> 4454 </average_prize>
                    </prize_pool>
                </tournament>

            </premiere_tournaments>

        </achievements>
    </teaminfo>
    <captain>
        <nick>Player1</nick>
        <role> Def </role>
        <captain_since>2011-01-14</captain_since>
        <Country>Country</Country>
    </captain>

    <player>
        <player_level>A-</player_level>
        <player_info streamer="y">
            <photo source="playerphoto.jpg"/>
            <nick>Playerino</nick>
            <rola>Att</rola>
            <style>roamer</style>
            <opinion_patch>Positive</opinion_patch>
            <fanpage adres="http://facebook.com/playerFanPage"/>
            <playergrade grade="Good"/>
        </player_info>
        <personal>
            <name>Matt</name>
            <surname>Kuk</surname>
            <age>22</age>
            <country>Counter</country>
        </personal>
    </player>
    <player>
        <player_level>A-</player_level>
        <player_info streamer="y">
            <photo source="playerphoto.jpg"/>
            <nick>Playerino</nick>
            <rola>Att</rola>
            <style>roamer</style>
            <opinion_patch>Positive</opinion_patch>
            <fanpage adres="http://facebook.com/playerFanPage"/>
            <playergrade grade="Good"/>
        </player_info>
        <personal>
            <name>Matt</name>
            <surname>Kuk</surname>
            <age>22</age>
            <country>Counter</country>
        </personal>
    </player>
    <sponsors>
        <sponsor>
            <companyname>Compname</companyname>
            <support_type>Periph, ads</support_type>
            <sponsor_page official_page="http://link.com"/>
            <fanpage fan_strona="http://lin43k.com"/>
        </sponsor>
    </sponsors>
    <perip>
        <mouse> mouse </mouse>
        <keyboard> keyboard </keyboard>
        <headphones> headphones </headphones>
    </perip>
</team>
```

I have been fighting with this awful thing all night, unfortunately the amount of materials on the web did not provide me with satisfactory methods to solve my issue. I want to make a "conversion" of xml file via xslt. I want to do it, in order to change its structure and possibly names of the attributes or elements.

I want to achieve something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylexslt3.xslt"?>
<team>
    <teaminfo>
        <logo source="logomym.jpg"/>
        <teampage address="http://www.site.com/"/>
        <name> Team name </name>
        <team_photo source="teamphoto.jpg"/>
        <game> Game1 </game>
    </teaminfo>
    <achievements>
        <premiere_tournaments>
            <tournament>
                <logoevent source="event1.jpg"/>
                <tournament_name> tournament name </tournament_name>
                <placing> 1 </placing>
                <prize_pool>
                    <earned_prize> 10600 </earned_prize>
                    <average_prize> 4454 </average_prize>
                </prize_pool>
            </tournament>
            <tournament>
                <logoevent source="event2.jpg"/>
                <tournament_name> tournament name </tournament_name>
                <placing> 3 </placing>
                <prize_pool>
                    <earned_prize> 10600 </earned_prize>
                    <average_prize> 4454 </average_prize>
                </prize_pool>
            </tournament>

        </premiere_tournaments>

    </achievements>

    <player>
        <nick>Player1</nick>
        <role> Def </role>
        <captain_since>2011-01-14</captain_since>
        <Country>Country</Country>
    </player>
    <player>
        <player_level>A-</player_level>
        <player_info streamer="y">
            <photo source="playerphoto.jpg"/>
            <nick>Playerino</nick>
            <rola>Att</rola>
            <style>roamer</style>
            <opinion_patch>Positive</opinion_patch>
            <fanpage adres="http://facebook.com/playerFanPage"/>
            <playergrade grade="Good"/>
        </player_info>
        <personal>
            <name>Matt</name>
            <surname>Kuk</surname>
            <age>22</age>
            <country>Counter</country>
        </personal>
    </player>
    <player>
        <player_level>A-</player_level>
        <player_info streamer="y">
            <photo source="playerphoto.jpg"/>
            <nick>Playerino</nick>
            <role>Att</role>
            <style>roamer</style>
            <opinion_patch>Positive</opinion_patch>
            <fanpage adres="http://facebook.com/playerFanPage"/>
            <playergrade grade="Good"/>
        </player_info>
        <personal>
            <name>Matt</name>
            <surname>Kuk</surname>
            <age>22</age>
            <country>Counter</country>
        </personal>
    </player>
</team>
```

Also if possible please include method for changing names of the elements. I tried to do this with multiple different methods but it seems like either the methods I haeve found were incorrect or I could not figure out how to use them properly. I will not post my xslt for now because it is insanely butchered.

Comment: I voted to close this question. Please try to break down your problem in smaller parts and post those individually as questions. _Always_ include, what you've got so far, what you've tried and where you think you're stuck. A general, possibly several 100 SLOC long XSLT stylesheet to be produced by answerers is not in the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: With a problem like this, you should be building upon the XSLT identity transform as a basis. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform. Then, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920639/rename-element-and-retain-attributes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781182/xslt-to-remove-elements-from-xml which tell you how to rename elements, and remove elements respectively. That should set you the road to writing some much leaner XSLT.

Comment: Reformatted XML with consistent indentation; added missing closing tag in second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've failed to explicitly state what's changed between the first and second examples (and you should also be showing your work so far even if it's insanely butchered), but from what I've been able to discern:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="teaminfo">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::achievements)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <!-- Move achievements to after teaminfo-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="achievements" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Rename captain to player -->
  <xsl:template match="captain">
    <player>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </player>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Omit sponsors and perip -->
  <xsl:template match="sponsors | perip" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there anything I missed?